# How does this expression arise: $\pi(10.5) = \phi (-z_{1-\alpha} + \sqrt{n} \frac{\mu_0-\mu}{2})$?

Tags: probability, statistics

$X_i$ is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distributed and the following is given $H_0: \mu \geq 12, H_a: \mu < 12$, and $\alpha=0.01$. I'm asked to calculate $\beta=P[TII]$ if in fact $\mu=10.5$

Now this is the first step that the solutions provide:
[image: solution]

Now I dont understand here why $\pi(10.5) = \phi (-z_{1-\alpha} + \sqrt{n} \frac{\mu_0-\mu}{2})$ ($\pi(\cdot)$ denotes the powerfunction here). This doesn't seem obvious and I don't see how they have derived this expression. (I do understand how they have standardized $\bar{X}$ but still I don't see the obvious reason for this expression). Could anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you get to that:
$$
P(\text{Type II error})=1-P(\text{Being in the Rejection Region}|\mu=10.5)\\=1-P\left(\frac{X-\mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}<-z_{1-\alpha}\right)=1-P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}<-z_{1-\alpha}+\frac{\mu_0-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
=1-P\left(Z<-z_{1-\alpha}+\frac{\mu_0-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)=1-\phi\left(-z_{1-\alpha}+\frac{\mu_0-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
So in your example, $\sigma=2$. A recommendation is to draw the densities and compare them and think about what the probability you are calculating actually means.

Comment: Thank you! How I solved this question myself was by first calculating for which values $H_0$ is rejected and by then calculating the probability that $H_0$ is not rejected given that $\mu=10.5$. Am I right that that is also correct? Because I think that that approach is more intuitive than using such a formula.

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing. Note that the way you formulate it you calculate: $P(\text{Accepting } H_0 | \mu=10.5)=1-P(\text{Rejecting } H_0|\mu=10.5)=1-P(\text{Being in the Rejection Region}|\mu=10.5)$. This is what I calculated above. Your method does the same thing, but in two steps.